# listview imagecell - images load in ios not in android from Azure

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to display some images from a web server rest call that I am making in xamarin forms.  The images that are listed in the web service load up just fine in iOS.  On Android, the images do not load.  The image that I am trying to load is:
https://homesmedia.blob.core.windows.net/homepictures/6fe0911b-8630-4151-83a0-06d072b8f110.jpg
The image is being pulled from azure blob storage.  It is an https connection, or at least it is supposed to be.

My Listview is defined:

```
<ListView x:Name="currentHomes" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding FirstImageOfHouse}" 
                           Text="{Binding address1}" Detail="{Binding addressFormatted}">

            </ImageCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

My class is defined as:

```
   public class Home
    {
        public string address1 { get; set; }
        public string address2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string iOSProvinceName { get; set; }
        public string postalCode { get; set; }
        public List<HomePicture> homePictures { get; set; }
        public List<HomeVideo> homeVideos { get; set; }
        public string agentLastName { get; set; }
        public string agentFirstName { get; set; }
        public string agentEmail { get; set; }
        public string FirstImageOfHouse
        {
            get
            {
                if (homePictures.Count > 0)
                {
                    return homePictures.First().pictureUrl;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
        public string addressFormatted
        {
            get
            {
                var str = string.Format("{0}, {1} {2}", city, iOSProvinceName, postalCode);
                return str;
            }
        }
    }
```

My Manifest is:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
<application android:label="McClureRealty.Android" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"></application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

My code is fairly simple to get the rest web service data:
            var homes = await WebServices.ws.HomesGetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            currentHomes.ItemsSource = homes;

```
    public async static Task<List<Home>> HomesGetAsync()
    {
        var url = CreateUrl(HomesUrl);
        var httpC = new MyHttpClient();
        var body = httpC.GetAsync(url).Result;
        var str = await body.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Home>>(str);
        httpC.Dispose();
        return res;
    }
```

The only error that I can find is in the "Application Output" window of VSMac:
BaseCellView: Error loading image: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ImageViewExtensions.UpdateBitmap (Android.Widget.ImageView imageView, Xamarin.Forms.IImageElement newView, Xamarin.Forms.IImageElement previousView, Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource newImageSource, Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource previousImageSource) [0x000f8] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Extensions\ImageViewExtensions.cs:49 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.BaseCellView.UpdateBitmap (Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource source, Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource previousSource) [0x0003a] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Cells\BaseCellView.cs:195

I am guessing that there is something I am missing in either my AndroidManifest or in ListView xaml, but I don't see anything.  there is some space in the listview as if it knows that there is supposed to be an image there, but it never displays the image.

I'm up to date on the most recent XF and nuget packages.  Any suggestions are appreciated on how to get the image to display.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Update your XF to latest version. I had similar problem with Azure. There was a bug in previous version of XF with SSL HttpClient implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm running on the most recent version of XF in all my projects in the solution.  I've played around with the http client settings in the project, but that didn't seem to do anything.  Non of this solved the problem.

Comment: In this case public string FirstImageOfHouse should be ImageSource not string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to make it of type imagesource.  I tried that, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I use the string format to load the link of the image to reproduce. It does not show the image well.

[image]

You could use `Uri` to load the image.

Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="currentHomes" ItemsSource="{Binding homes}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ImageCell
                    Detail="{Binding addressFormatted}"
                    ImageSource="{Binding FirstImageOfHouse}"
                    Text="{Binding address1}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Home> homes { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        homes = new ObservableCollection<Home>();
        homes.Add(new Home()
        {
            address1 = "This is an ImageCell",
            addressFormatted = "This is some detail text",
            FirstImageOfHouse = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://homesmedia.blob.core.windows.net/homepictures/6fe0911b-8630-4151-83a0-06d072b8f110.jpg"))/*"https://homesmedia.blob.core.windows.net/homepictures/6fe0911b-8630-4151-83a0-06d072b8f110.jpg"))*/
        });

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
public class Home
{
    public ImageSource FirstImageOfHouse { get; set; }
    public string address1 { get; set; }
    public string addressFormatted { get; set; }
}
```

Permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Wendy.  I have changed to use an ImageSource coming from my objects.  I have used an observablecollection (not sure why I forgot that earlier).  I have also tried to see about putting the assignment of the homes within a call to Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread().  None of this has worked out.

Comment: Have you try the code i provided? It could show the image well. What is the code you used?

Comment: Thanks @Wendy.  I made the necessary changes, but it did not display.  I am going to try some other things, but it will be a few days.  Thanks for your help so far.  :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I decided to create a custom viewcell to try something different.  With a custom viewcell, the image comes across just fine.  I've got a bunch of work to do to format things right, but this is kinda what I want.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Wendy.